# VBA Code to Copy Data from Row 2 to Last Row of Data on One Sheet and Paste to the First Empty Row of Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with multiple sheets within a workbook. Each sheet has an identical header row. I would like to write a macro to copy a range of data from each sheet (A2:L2 to the last row of data on a sheet) and paste it into the first empty cell in Column A of master sheet.

What I have below doesn't seem to work. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A2:L10000).Clear

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A2:L" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
Range("A30000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("A2:L" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
Range("A30000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there from the looks of it. It looks like you've recorded a macro which is a good place to start. The reason your specific code might not work is because of `Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A2:L10000).Clear`. You're missing the end quote inside of the range. In any case though, I've chosen to leave that out so you don't accidentally clear your sheet when you're moving data across

So generally it's good to avoid using `select` and `activate`, but with a recorder you don't have much say in the matter. Below you can see how I can do operations directly with the range.

It's important to find the last row of the master sheet as well as your current sheet each time so you know the range you want to copy and where you can paste it. It's important to remember that you're always finding the last **filled** cell, so in the case of a paste destination, you need to add one more to the row value so you don't accidentally overwrite some data.

For loops are pretty useful, I'm not sure what names you have for the rest of your sheets, but luckily in VBA you can use `For each`. so what this does is it cycles through every single item that you specify. In this case I've specified worksheets. The only problem now though, is we don't want to try copying and pasting into the same Master Sheet, so we need to do a quick check to make sure we're not on the master sheet. I've done this simply by comparing the name of the worksheet to what you've put as the name of the master sheet.

Interestingly when you copy something, you only need to specify the top left cell and it'll fill in the rest of it. It makes life a little easier because you don't need to figure out the exact dimensions of the array you're pasting. The `Copy` function in VBA has an optional parameter called `Destination` which you can use to tell it where you want to paste it right away.

It's also good to fully specify ranges when you're using them so instead of `Range`, you can see how I use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range`. This tells the computer exactly where you want to reference; whereas `Range` makes the computer sort of guess, so it assumes you mean the active sheet, which might not be what you want.

```
Sub Paster()
    Dim LastRowCurr As Long
    Dim LastRowMaster As Long
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    For Each wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not wksht.Name = "Master Sheet" Then
            LastRowCurr = wksht.Cells(wksht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            LastRowMaster = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(Worksheets("Master Sheet").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range("A2:L" & LastRowCurr).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(LastRowMaster, "A")
        End If
    Next wksht
End Sub
```

Comment: If this worked for you please mark the answer as accepted (checkmark under the voting buttons) so people know the question has been fully answered.